# Keep only non zero missing values in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

How to select only the non-null columns in descending order from the dataframe.

Here is the dataframe:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame( { 'a': [1,2,np.nan,np.nan],
                    'b':  [10,20,30,40],
                   'c': [1,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan]})
     a   b    c
0  1.0  10  1.0
1  2.0  20  NaN
2  NaN  30  NaN
3  NaN  40  NaN
```

I can do this:

```py
df.isnull().sum().sort_values(ascending=False)
c    3
a    2
b    0
```

But I want to CHAIN multiple commands to a single line so that it gives result in one line.

I tried:
`df.isnull().sum().sort_values(ascending=False).filter(lambda x: x>0)`
it fails

I know this:

```py
temp = df.isnull().sum().sort_values(ascending=False)
temp[temp>0]
c    3
a    2
```

But I am looking way to chaining continuation in ONE-LINE.

Required:

```
df.isnull().sum().sort_values(ascending=False).somefunction( x > 0)
```

**Update**
I found a way converting series to dataframe and then using query.

```
df.isnull().sum().sort_values(ascending=False).to_frame().rename(columns={0:'temp'}).query("temp > 0")
```

This looks long and superfluous. Is there a better way ?

Comment: what is the desired output?

Comment: desired output is output of `temp[temp>0]` as given in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is confused for `filter` , since it is work for index , not the value

```
df.isnull().sum().loc[lambda x : x>0].sort_values(ascending=False)
Out[147]: 
a    2
c    3
dtype: int64
```

Comment: This is a lot shorter than my method of dataframe conversion. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I like the idea of `loc` with a callback here. Very nifty!

Comment: This answer is absolute correct. However, the pasted output doesn't match the actual output. I tried to edit the pasted output to match the actual output, but some dudes rejected. The actual output order is `c 3`, `a 2` because of `sort_values(ascending=False)`. I have no intention in nitpicking. This is a refreshing answer, so I just want to fix the pasted output to make it a good reference for someone else later on. WeNYoBen or @cs95, could you change the order of the pasted output?

Answer (score 2):

There are, of course, many ways of doing this, but in general I would not recommend using a lambda or a filter where you pass a python function as this will make things quite slow if your series is larger.
In your case, you could instead do
1. Replace 0 with nan and drop the nans.

```
df.isnull().sum().replace(0, np.nan).dropna().sort_values(ascending=False).astype(int)
```

The downside of this is that you need to type convert twice (nan is always a float, never an int).
 2. Use the query function.

```
df.isnull().sum().sort_values(ascending=False).to_frame('value').query('value!=0')['value'].rename(None)
```

The downside with this method is that it only exist on dataframes, so you need to convert the series to one first. However, for large series this should be cheaper than type converting since the underlying array remains the same.

Answer (score 1):

Using `.loc` with the mask by `isna` and `any` on `axis=0`:

```
df.loc[:, df.isna().any()].isna().sum().sort_values(ascending=False)

Out[1845]:
c    3
a    2
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be answered using much more efficient way through numpy:

```
s = data.isnull().sum()
mask = (s.values > 0)
pd.Series(s.values[mask], s.index[mask]).sort_values(ascending=False)
```

[Clear comparison of time complexity among all methods](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNgNK.png)